# MCMC: Integral Approximation?

Tags: probability, markov-chains, monte-carlo

Let's say I want to approximate the following integral:
$$I = \int_0^5 R(x)f(x)dx$$
where $R(x)$ is a Rayleigh distribution and $f(x)$ is some generic function.

I generate $n$ samples using Metropolis Hastings MCMC.

Now is the approximation simply:
$$I' = \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^nf(x_i)$$
where the individual samples $x_i$ are generated from Metropolis Hastings?

Is the target pdf in Metropolis Hastings MCMC only $R(x)$? or the entire function?

Any generic background/resources concerning the defining features of MCMC would be great!

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The generating PDF for $x_i$s in the MH algorithm must be the Truncated Rayleigh distribution since your integration bounds are limited. So you must actually have $$f_{x_i}(x)={R(x)\over \Pr\{X<5\}}$$where $f_{x_i}(x)$ is the PDF of $x_i$ and $X$ is a Rayleigh (not truncated) random variable.

Comment: that makes sense! conveniently $\text{Pr}\{X < 5\} \approx 1$, which I think is why the problem was phrased in such a way. In general though, I will keep that in mind!

Comment: Good luck in the rest of your way!